# How do i define a global variable from asynchronous call with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I want to use single_video variable in outside of the controller function. It prints well in first console log. However it gives a single_video is undefined error in second console.log which is outside of the controller function. Because of the asynchronousity.

```
   var single_video;
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('randomVideo', function($scope, $http) {
    var onSuccess = function(response){
        $scope.video = response.data; 
        single_video = $scope.video;
        //First console.log
        console.log('1st ID='+single_video.yt_id);
    };
    var onError = function(reason){
        $scope.error = "There is an error about getting random_video.php";
    };
   $http.get("http://www.ytmdb.com/ytvideo/api/random_video.php")
   .then(onSuccess, onError);
});
//Second console.log
console.log('2nd ID='+single_video.yt_id);
```

Comment: What you labeled as *"Second console.log"* is actually the first console.log. What you are asking for is simply impossible. the "second" console.log will never be able to give you that value.

Comment: @KevinB They are same but i get an "undefined" error in second one. Second console.log prints before single_video has been defined due to asynchronousity. Is there a way pf doing it with callback function or etc. My jacascript background is very poor.

Comment: You have to access the global variable **after** the callback ran. So the code that accesses the global variable has to be in or called from the callback. But then there is no need for a global variable anymore.

Comment: Look at it this way. That global variable will ***eventually*** contain the value you want it to, you'll just have to wait to access it until after it has been populated. However, to know when it is populated, you'll need to use a success callback which will have the value as a parameter, thus making the global variable redundant. If you needed that value in multiple places, that's what the promise returned from `$http` methods is for.

Comment: What you're asking for is impossible by definition. Why don't you rephrase your question in a way that reveals what problem you're actually trying to solve. Code management after asynchronous callbacks?

Comment: I think you pretty much nailed it yourself. *"Second console.log prints before single_video has been defined due to asynchronousity"* Which is why you can't call the `log` function then.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that you invoke inside the `success` callback passing your variable as a parameter to the function:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('randomVideo', function($scope, $http) {
    var onSuccess = function(response){
        $scope.video = response.data; 
        single_video = $scope.video;
        //First console.log
        console.log('1st ID='+single_video.yt_id);
        test(single_video.yt_id);
    };
    var onError = function(reason){
        $scope.error = "There is an error about getting random_video.php";
    };
    $http.get("http://www.ytmdb.com/ytvideo/api/random_video.php")
    .then(onSuccess, onError);
});
function test(a)
{
    console.log('2nd ID='+a);
}
```

Comment: If you're defining your controller in strict mode (and you should be!) this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Define your global variables in a factory service and inject the service in your angular controller where ever you need. (Note: try to put everything in an IIFE)

Global Variables using services, here is an example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('MySvc', function() {
return {
  name : 'your name'
};
});
```

and in a controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, MySvc) {
$scope.name = MySvc.name;
}
```